# Typing letters to a text widget by pressing a button in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to type a specific letter into a text box in tkinter by pressing a button with that specific character written on it.

```
mainmenu = Tk()
mainmenu.title("PROF NAME")
mainmenu.geometry("1200x600")

canvas = Canvas(mainmenu, width = 1200, height = 600)
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand = True)
canvas.create_text(600, 50, text = '교수님의 초성을 입력해주세요', font='Arial 30')

letters = Text(mainmenu, width=20, height=1, font="times 15")
letters.place(x=490, y=140)

def buttonclick():
    letters.insert(END, "ㄱ")

btn1 = Button(mainmenu, padx=2, pady=2, text="ㄱ", font="times 12", command=buttonclick)
btn1.place(x=360, y=90)
```

So basically the character ㄱ is what I would like to put into the text box 'letters' when I press it. What might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: why can't you simply type letters in the text box? and I can't reproduce the issue, when I press the button it inserts the character in the text box

Comment: I get the character "ㄱ" in the text box `letters` when `btn1` is clicked.  So what is your problem actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should do what you want it to, but correct me if I'm wrong:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Text, Button, END

mainmenu = Tk()
mainmenu.title("PROF NAME")
mainmenu.geometry("1200x600")

canvas = Canvas(mainmenu, width=1200, height=600)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
canvas.create_text(600, 50, text="교수님의 초성을 입력해주세요", font="Arial 30")

letters = Text(mainmenu, width=20, height=1, font="times 15")
letters.place(x=490, y=140)


def button_click(letter):
    return lambda: letters.insert(END, letter)


btn1 = Button(mainmenu, padx=2, pady=2, text="h", font="times 12")
btn1.configure(command=button_click(btn1.cget("text")))
btn1.place(x=360, y=90)

mainmenu.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!
I think I need some research about lambda command :D

Comment: It's basically the same as writing a function, then returning that function. All I'm doing there is creating a function specifically for that button, which inserts it's text into the `letters` object. That means every time you call `button_click(letter)` it creates a separate function which inserts that specific letter/text.

Comment: @RolvApneseth Why not just use `command=lambda: letters.insert("end", btn1.cget("text"))`? It makes the code much easier to read. Or even better `def button_click(): letters.insert("end", btn1.cget("text"))` and then `command=button_click`.

Comment: I wanted it to be usable for multiple buttons, which I assume op will want to do